# Is there an equivalent of bulk contains?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there some utility to check whether a sequence contains multiple elements instead of using `Contains` repeatedly?

```
List<string> containter = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    containter.Add("string #" + i);
}

if (containter.Contains("string #2") &&       //Is it possible to replace this with one call passing two strings to improve efficiency 
    containter.Contains("string #6"))
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: `seq.Count()>1`? Surely you mean something else?

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking. Why not provide your current code so we have some context?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question I added an example to improve clarity

Comment: @NickolayKondratyev I've updated my answer in respond. Please, check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the updated question, I've modified my answer:

```
List<string> containter = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    containter.Add("string #" + i);
}
//define a checklist
List<string> checkList = new List<string> { "string #2", "string #6" };
//we're in, if every item in checkList is present in container
if (!checkList.Except(containter).Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("true");
}
```

Still you may use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx). But in this context it would be nice to use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) method.

If every item in `checkList` is present in the `container` the resulting sequence would contain no elements, so `Any` should return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to compare two sequences, and want to know if one sequence contains all of the elements in another sequence.

```
var outer = new List<String>() { "1", "2", "3" };
var inner = new List<String>() { "1", "2" };
bool outerContainsAllInnerElements = inner.TrueForAll(i => outer.Contains(i));
```

Alternatively, you could use `Intersect()`, but that will project your items into a new sequence when you attempt to get its count. If that's what you want, great, but if you don't need to know which elements intersect, then `TrueForAll()` would save that overhead.

```
var outer = new List<String>() { "1", "2", "3" };
var inner = new List<String>() { "1", "2" };
var elementsInBoth = outer.Intersect(inner);
bool outerContainsAllInnerElements = (elementsInBoth.Count() == inner.Count());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Any`:

```
string s = "I am a string";
string[] check = { "is", "my" };

Console.WriteLine(check.Any(x => s.Contains(x))); // False

s = "This is a string";
Console.WriteLine(check.Any(x => s.Contains(x))); // True

s = "my string";
Console.WriteLine(check.Any(x => s.Contains(x))); // True
```